# Why isn't the compiler throwing an error when assigining a number/bool to a string var

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript and I'm trying to understand how Javascript var types work, 
I created a simple class: and restricted the name property to string, but when I insert a number to my string variable I get no error and my string property holds the number as it was a string... am I missing something?
When I debugged it, I found that name was 345.
//done in ts

```
class Customer {
    public name: string = "";
    validate(input: string): string {
        alert("hey");
        return "hey";
    }
}
```

The code that uses my class

```
 <script>        
        var tito = new Customer();
        tito.name = 345;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the first portion of code was done using Typescript, the code that uses that class seems to be placed in an HTML and it's pure Javascript, that's why the types are not being checked, since this is not being compiled by Typescript.
In order to use type checking your code needs to be placed in a .ts file:

```
// Inside a .ts file
var tito = new Customer();
tito.name = 345;
```

Comment: Thanks, if I understand right, the best way to create an obj in ts is to pass my data from js to.ts and in the ts to creae my object ?

Comment: @Damkulul could you please give us more information regarding why would you want to create an object on js instead of on a .ts file?

Comment: well according to a tutorial that i found, the obj was declared in the script tag and used the obj's class like in c# when you create an obj in the 'main' section...and in my case use the .ts as a class..